# Credit Card Terminal Integration with PHP POS system

Tags: php, credit-card, visa, mastercard

I am trying to build a PHP POS System which is deployed on-site, with a credit card terminal. May I ask, beside STRIPE, EVO and the likes, is there anyway I can send parameters to the terminal and once paid, the terminal will sent a parameter back to my PHP application? Are there any tutorials on this? Please advise.

Comment: This question is a bit broad.  It depends on the procol being used by your card terminal, you will have to implement that protocol.  Generally spoken, what you want to do is possible.  But it really depends on the vendor.  Maybe you want to explain a bit more what terminal from which vendor you are using, and for which country?

Comment: I am in SIngapore and I am linking directly with the banks